# jQuery add class and sleep then remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have an image map which has several divs on it as city points. And I wrote a class in css to animate those points' color, so I can add that class through jQuery, wait sometime and remove the class. The goal is to animate those points randomly (add class, wait, remove class at random), but currently I am stuck with waiting before removing the class. I tried different solutions, including those that are posted on this site, but no result. Hre is the code:

```
        function builtCities() {
            if ($('body.page-service-map').size()) {
                var content = $('#region-content .content'),
                    cityDot = '<div class="city-dot"></div>',
                    cities = [
                        'moscow',
                        'saint-petersburg',
                        'krasnodar',
                        'rostov-na-donu',
                        'tyumen',
                        'omsk',
                        'irkutsk'
                    ];

                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    content.append(cityDot);
                }

                $('body.page-service-map .city-dot').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).addClass(cities[index]);
                });

                // animation
                for (var j = 0; j < cities.length; j++) {                       
                    function partA(partB) {
                        $('.city-dot').eq(j).addClass('animate');
                        window.setTimeout(partB, 1000);
                    } partA(partB);

                    function partB() {
                        $('.city-dot').eq(j).removeClass('animate');
                    }           
                }


            }
        } builtCities();
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because of closures. Do it like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < cities.length; j++) { 
    $('.city-dot').eq(j).addClass('animate');
    window.setTimeout((function (j) {
        return function () {
            $('.city-dot').eq(j).removeClass('animate');
        };
    }(j)), 1000);
}
```

Your current one doesn't work because your `j` variable will be persisted and will actually be equal to `cities.length` at the time you're calling `partB`. To get around this, the above calls a function passing in `j` which will return another function using a separate variable (the parameter `j`) that will use the correct index.

Comment: I put a debugger into the timeout and now I see that animation works, but may be timeout is too fast. I mean it doesn't wait as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you got the parentheses inside `setTimeout` right?

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < cities.length; j++) {
      $('.city-dot').eq(j).addClass('animate');
      window.setTimeout((function (j) {       
       return function () {
        $('.city-dot').eq(j).removeClass('animate');        
       };
      }(j)), 1000);
     }

Comment: Should work, here is an example using `alert()` http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zhjCV/

Comment: using alert in this case is not a good idea cause it stops executing of js itself.

Comment: Yes I know, it's the simplest example to demonstrate that your code works fine.

Comment: In your example set timeout is not working at next iteration. Alert '1' occurs immediately after alert '0'

Comment: Is there a way to set new timeout on every iteration?

Comment: You're expecting ot have them spaced out? If so use `j` in your `timeout` length http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zhjCV/1/